# String concatenation in a ruby block

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand why the same concatenation operation builds a string in a normal context, but builds an array when run in an each block.

For example, this concatenation works as expected

```
irb(main):027:0> str = "test"
=> "test"
irb(main):028:0> str += "test"
=> "testtest"
irb(main):029:0> str += "test"
=> "testtesttest"
```

But when run iteratively in an each block, it builds an array:

```
irb(main):030:0> str = ""
=> ""
irb(main):031:0> list = ["a", "b", "c"]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
irb(main):032:1* list.each do |c|
irb(main):033:1*   str += c
irb(main):034:0> end
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: "it builds an array" - no, it doesn't. You think you're looking at `str`, but you are not. What you see is `list`, because `each` returns the collection as its return value

Comment: There's also [`concat`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/String.html#method-i-concat) which can concatenate multiple objects. That along with the `*` operator allows you to concatenate an array of strings in one step: `str.concat(*list)` (see [Calling Methods – `Array` to Argument Conversion](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion))

Answer (score 4):

When provided a block, [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) returns `self` (i.e., `list`).

```rb
irb(main):001:0> list = ["a", "b", "c"]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
irb(main):002:0> list.each {}
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Inspecting `str` afterwards shows that it was indeed changed.

```rb
irb(main):001:0> str = ""
=> ""
irb(main):002:0> list = ["a", "b", "c"]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
irb(main):003:1* list.each do |c|
irb(main):004:1*   str += c
irb(main):005:0> end
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
irb(main):006:0> str
=> "abc"
```

Comment: JFYI, in ruby the convention for writing down instance methods names is `Array#each`. `Array.each` or `Array::each` means method `each` on the class `Array` itself.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Amended.